# Re-structuring a multidimensional array for conditional variables

Tags: php

I'm currently dumping this array:

```
      0 => {#407 ▼
        +"item_id": "11873"
        +"type": "Item Title"
        +"comment": "Item Title"
        +"typet_id": "2"
      }
      1 => {#408 ▼
        +"item_id": "11873"
        +"type": "Item Instruction"
        +"comment": "test instruction"
        +"typet_id": "2"
      }
      2 => {#409 ▼
        +"item_id": "11875"
        +"type": "Item Title"
        +"comment": "Test Title"
        +"typet_id": "2"
      }
      3 => {#410 ▼
        +"item_id": "11874"
        +"type": "Item Title"
        +"comment": "Item Title"
        +"typet_id": "2"
      }
      4 => {#411 ▼
        +"item_id": "11874"
        +"type": "Item Instruction"
        +"comment": "test instruction"
        +"typet_id": "2"
      }
```

and it does show all of the correct data, but I'm trying to figure out how to set up a foreach loop with the structure I need.

As you can see, two of the items above have the same item_id because they each have different 'type' values. So each Item can have a Item title and a Item instruction, and I'm just getting multiple results for each Item.

I'm trying to get a structure where they are grouped by item_id and then I can have both 'type' values

```
     0 => {#407 ▼
        +"item_id": "11873"
            2=> {
            type: "Item Title"
            comment: "Item Title"
            },
            {
            type:"Item Instruction"
            comment: "Test Instruction"
            }
        typet_id:"2"
      }
      1 => {#408 ▼
         +"item_id": "11874"
            2=> {
            type: "Item Title"
            comment: "Item Title"
            },
            {
            type:"Item Instruction"
            comment: "Test Instruction"
            }
        typet_id:"2"
      }
      2 => {#409 ▼
         +"item_id": "11875"
            2=> {
            type: "Item Title"
            comment: "Item Title"
            }
        typet_id:"2"
      }
```

I know I can set the first foreach around the id, but I'm unclear how to structure the rest to get the correct output I'm looking for so that I can differentiate between the type and comment. Basically if type is Title, I need to set it to one variable and if type is Instruction I need to set it to a different value because they will go in different columns of an html table.

```
    foreach($getItem as $id => $components){
        $id = $components->item_id;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, in your SQL, you can just write `order by item_id asc` in the end and you will always find the `type` and `instruction` next to each other. So, in your array, you could access the `instruction` in the `$index + 1` location in your for loop.

Comment: But I would still have duplicates right? In other words, that still would give me two separate indeces for one single ID

Comment: In my first block I show 5 indeces for 3 IDs, where my 2nd block shows that I should only have 3 indeces

Comment: @TomN. I don't gather how you distinguish with that data structure title, description, ets

Comment: @TomN. You could reorder it through PHP but since you said `because they will go in different columns of an html table`, so you could just access it with loop indexes itself rather than manually taking the effort to reorder the SQL result. To skip the next duplicate, you could just do `$i+=2` instead of `$i++` in your for loop.

Comment: Thank you, I actually think I figured out a solution using ```$result = array();
        foreach($getItem as $item){
            $result[$item->item_id][] = $item;
        }```
This will give me only one result for each ID, then I can use if statements on the blade for the table columns